# How do I change the default output location of the quarto document in Rstudio?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

For example, my quarto file is in `D:\myr\index.qmd`, how can I output the generated PDF file to `E:\myoutput`?

Answer (score 4):

The output file location can be specified with the `output_file` argument of [`quarto_render()`](https://quarto-dev.github.io/quarto-r/reference/quarto_render.html) function from [`{quarto}`](https://quarto-dev.github.io/quarto-r/index.html) package.

So Ideally we can try something like this,

```
quarto::quarto_render("index.qmd", output_file = "E:/index.pdf")
```

**index.qmd**

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

## Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:
```

But this leads me to an error,

```
ERROR: The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive. (os error 17), 
rename 'index.pdf' -> 'E:/index.pdf'
```

**Version Info**

```
> xfun::session_info()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044), RStudio 2022.7.1.554

> quarto::quarto_version()
[1] ‘1.0.38’
```

---

### Solution

We can use this function that will move the rendered output file to the desired directory.

```
render_qmd <- function(input_file, output_path, file_ext, ...) {
    # Extract just the input file name (without the file-extension)
    file_name <- xfun::sans_ext(input_file)

    # render the input document and output file will be in the
    # current working directory.
    quarto::quarto_render(input = input_file, output_format = file_ext, ...)

    # name of the rendered output file
    output_name <- paste0(file_name, ".", file_ext)

    # move the file to the output path
    fs::file_move(paste0(output_name), output_path)

    msg <- paste0(paste0(output_name, collapse = " and "), " moved to ", output_path)
    message(msg)
}

render_qmd("index.qmd", "E:/myoutput", file_ext = "pdf")
```

Note that, the packages `{quarto}`, [`{fs}`](https://fs.r-lib.org/), [`{xfun}`](https://github.com/yihui/xfun) are used in this function. So make sure that you have these pkgs installed.

Comment: Another option is moving the files afterwards using the `fs` package: get the paths using `paths <- fs::dir_ls("Documents/input_folder", regexp = "html|pdf")`, then move the files tot he desired location:
`fs::file_move(paths, "Documents/desired_folder")`

Comment: Hey shafee, any ideas why this occurs? Seems odd that this issue hasn't been addressed in the year since it's been asked.

Comment: @putschko: Quarto was meant to work (only) with relative paths, which is an annoying limitation but part of the Quarto philosophy.